# Add all numbers in a text file under windows

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I have a multiline text file that I want to add up all the numbers from and output the result to a second file.

ex: in file.txt

```
29218

76

48

44

41
```

sum = 29218 + 76 + 48 + 44 + 41 = 29427

export to file2.txt

> 29427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a batch script you are after, maybe the following could be help you out:

[Batch file to sum numbers from text files and write that total value to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201801/batch-file-to-sum-numbers-from-text-files-and-write-that-total-value-to-text-fil)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's sum something via cmd:

```
set i=1
set j=2
set /a sum=i+j
echo %sum%
```

It prints `3` as expected.

Second step: read values from file:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (file.txt) do echo %%A
```

This code prints all values from your file.txt.

After it you can unite both tricks:

```
set sum=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (file.txt) do set /a sum=sum+%%A
echo %sum% > file2.txt
```

(it prints 29427 as you asked)